# Сравнение переменной с каждой строкой в файле

Tags: python, строки, файлы, сравнение

Стоит следующая задача:

Имеется некий файл `file.txt`, в нем содержатся слова, по одному на строку, типа:

```
Jsvdjdbe
Hsvdicow
Bskviege 
Bekvieve 
Pnksvqyd
```

И есть переменная `cwlcjrvd`

Нужно каждую строку из файла сравнить с этой переменной и вернуть либо `True` либо `False`

Помогите пожалуйста советом или подскажите в какую сторону копать

Comment: Прочитай файл строками и сравнивай.

Answer (score 2):

Сравнение с учетом регистра:

```
with open("file.txt") as f:
    lines = f.readlines() # прочитать файл построчно в списко

for line in lines:
    if "cwlcjrvd" == line[:-1]: # [:-1] - все символы, кроме последнего, который перевод строки
        print(True)
    else:
        print(False)
```

Если регистр (заглавная буква или строчная) не имеет значения, то нужно оба слова привести к одному регистру:

```
for line in lines:
    if "cwlcjrvd".lower() == line[:-1].lower():
        print(True)
    else:
        print(False)
```

Answer (score 1):

Более pythonic:

```
def word_in_file(word, name_file):

    with open(name_file) as f:
        lines = f.read().split()

    return True if word in lines else False

word = "cwlcjrvd"
name_file = "file.txt"

word_in_file(word, name_file)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    file.txt
======================    
    Jsvdjdbe
    Hsvdicow
    Bskviege
    Bekvieve
    Pnksvqyd
=======================

var = 'Bskviege'
with open('file.txt') as f:
    lines = [_.replace('\n', '') for _ in f.readlines()]  # прочитать файл построчно в списко

print('\n'.join([str((var == val)) for val in lines]))

# False
# False
# True
# False
# False
```